# Retrieve data from large SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have full control permission over a SharePoint list. I am trying to retrieve all the items from a list which is having more than 60,000 items in it.

I have tried using export to excel and datasheet view but they are retrieving up to 52,000 items. Also I don't have access to central administration. Is there any way to retrieve all the list items without using PowerShell script and disabling list threshold.

My SharePoint version is 2010.

Comment: You can apply some filter on views. Export the views and then merge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an end-user of the SharePoint list you can retrieve up to 52,000 list items through **Export to excel** option. If the list has more items (**more than 52,000**) then you can use **Open with Access** option from the list ribbon. There are 2 options you can download a copy of the list or you can sync the list with your access table. After you retrieved the items using MS access now you can export those data in access to MS excel or PDF or text file.

Answer (score 3):

If you could get access to Central Admin, you could increase the List View Threshold (LVT):

1. Login to Central Admin
2. Go to Application Management -> Manage Web Applications
3. Pick the Web application for which you want to change the LVT (If you only have 1 web app plus the central admin one, the one you want to pick is the 1 web app; changing this for the central admin does you no good)
4. In the ribbon above, click General Settings. That will bring down a menu, from which you should pick Resource Throttling
5. Change the LVT (first item in this list) to another value and press OK, but please try to keep it to a reasonable number!

[SOURCE](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dinaayoub/2010/04/22/sharepoint-2010-how-to-change-the-list-view-threshold-and-other-resource-throttling-settings/)

NOTE: Don't forget to change it back to a reasonable number after you done your export.

Another option is to export items in batches, using views or script.

If you can't use Central Admin or script, views is the only option I guess. Create view with filter `ID is less or equal 30.000` and another with filter `ID is greater than 30.000` for example. Export them separately then merge them in Excel.

Comment: could you please explain more about export items in batches.

Answer (score 1):

you can try querying the list by overriding the SPQueryThrottleOption of spquery

```
SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
SPList list = web.Lists["BigList"];
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
query.QueryThrottleMode = SPQueryThrottleOption.Override;
SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);
litMessage.Text = String.Format(“This list contains {0} items”, tems.Count);
```

Note line no-4.

And if you want to use CONTENTITERATOR for Retrieving items in batches:[here is the refer](https://andrewwburns.com/2012/07/13/dealing-with-large-lists-part-3-the-contentiterator/)

Comment: is it possible to export the list items to excel sheet by using content iterator. If yes how could I achieve that.